# Python - batch file communication

Tags: python, shell, batch-file

I have a batch file, something like this

```
@echo off
echo Good Morning
set /P convert=Convert? ^(y^/n^):
echo Favourite Day?
echo Monday:1 Tuesday:2...
set /P day=Number:
echo %day%
echo %convert%
```

And when I try to open it with python and subprocess with

```
import subprocess
popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out = popen.communicate(input=b'n\n1\n')[0]
```

I get

```
Echo is off
```

and when I try to go line by line with

```
for line in popen.stdout
```

the subprocess just freezes. Is it possible to imitate user input in a batch file with python?

Answer (score 0):

I called the batch file you included `test.bat`.

When I run this completed form of your code (Windows 10, python 3.8.5) without changing anything (except the loop at the end)

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'test.bat'
popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out = popen.communicate(input=b'n\n1\n')[0]
for line in out.decode('cp1252').splitlines():
    print(f'LINE: {line}')
```

I get (mostly) expected output.

```
LINE: Good Morning
LINE: Convert? (y/n):Favourite Day?
LINE: Monday:1 Tuesday:2...
LINE: Number:1
LINE: n
```

The only difference is that I was reading `out` rather than `popen.stdout`

Comment: Thanks for the response (and edit)
I tried the last loop, but I still get the "LINE: Number:ECHO is off." instead of 1. The only difference is that I am using Python 3.7. I will try it on 3.8